# What are some good USB-2.0-powered SDHC/SD card readers?

Tags: card-reader, sdhc

I'm looking to get a camera bag reader for SD/SDHC cards so that I can avoid having to plug the camera itself in to the computer.

I'm aware of the [SanDisk MicroMate](http://www.sandisk.com/products/readers-accessories/micromate-sdhc).  My only concern with that one is that it's wide enough that if I wanted to use it at home I'd have to unplug the rest of my USB devices in order to create a slot large enough to plug it in.  There's also this [Kingston MobileLiteG2](http://www.kingston.com/flash/mobileliteG2_reader.asp) but it looks it would suffer from similar problems.

I suppose I could always buy a short USB extension cable and plug them in that way.

For the holy grail of recommendations, a Firewire reader with native SDHC support would be amazing.  Of course, I don't know if SDHC is fast enough to get any benefit from Firewire.  Probably not.  Still, I'd be able to chain devices together with a Firewire 400 device which I can't do with USB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would buy a short USB extension as you mentions.
They are worth their eight in gold. i have one running from my box to just under the edge of my desk where i secured it with some screws.

I never have to go behind my box.

for a decent SD reader, i would look to amazon. 
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sdhc+reader&x=0&y=0

i have a few i cant really tell a difference

EDIT:
actually check this out.
[http://www.amazon.com/Kingston-Flash-Memory-Reader-FCR-HS219/dp/B00109Y2DQ/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1290624536&sr=8-4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00109Y2DQ)